# An asp.net page structure question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In Default.aspx I have below code,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Place 1
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Place 2
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I put a button on the page to write "I am clicked!".

And codebehind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = "Button";           
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("I am clicked!");
    }
}
```

When I build, the view of page is like below:

```
Place 1
Place 2 
Button
```

When I click the button, "I am clicked!" is appeared before Place 1.

The result is:

```
I am clicked! Place 1
Place 2 
Button
```

Why does it appear before "Place 1"?
Have you got any idea?

Comment: You might want to look into the ASP.NET Page Life cycle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx to better understand why this is happening, but the answers below are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because control events are processed before page `PreRender` event. So all page content would be rendered after manual output within a control event handler.

Basically you should not do this using `Response.Write()`, simply:

```
button.Text ="I am clicked!";
```

[MSDN - ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

> **Control events**
>   Use these events to handle specific control events, such as a Button
>   control's Click event or a TextBox control's TextChanged event.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Because you are writing directly in the response. If you want to have the text on specific position on the page, put an asp:label control on the page and set the Text property of the label control in the Button1_Click

Answer (score 3):

that's to be expected - look at the [Page-Live-Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Please observe that the *rendering* is **after** the *postback event handling*.

Normaly you don't use Response.Write put a control or asp-tag to output something in ASP.net